# I2C seems to work but all register reads return 0s

Tags: i2c, psoc

I'm debugging an audio codec WM8962B via I2C. I wrote basic code for a manual I2C read operation of a given register. I'm using PSoC 5LP to do it.

The 7bit slave address is 0x1A and I'm trying to read the device ID [CUST_ID] and [CHIP_REV] to make sure my interface works as expected. The default value is 0x069F for the word. I'm expecting to see 0x06 (0b00000100) for the upper byte and 0x9F for the lower byte.

[image]

Below is the output on the scope.
[image]

I compared my output to a defined multiple I2C byte read sequence below:
[image]

The START, STOP, ACK and NACK bits all seem to line up and agree with the SCL/SDA transitions. However, no matter what register I read from I get only 0s. What could this indicate and what am I overlooking?

Here's my code:
[image]

Comment: please, no pictures of text ... the code cannot be copied and tested ... remove the picture and insert the actual text ... also, some people here cannot view pictures

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The I2C waveforms on the scope shot look like valid I2C, so that rules out common errors like forgetting to include SCL/SDA pullup resistors, or having too much bus capacitance, etc. At the bit/datalink level, the waveforms look fine. The device is acknowledging its write and read addresses.

According to the [Cirrus WM8962 Datasheet](https://statics.cirrus.com/pubs/proDatasheet/WM8962_Rev4.4.pdf), On page 185, Figure 63 "Control Interface 2-wire (I2C) Register Read", shows the register address as two 8-bit fields A15-A8 and A7-A0. But in your scope shot your firmware is only sending 8 bits of register address before the repeated start. So this incomplete address field may be why the WM8962 is not sending back the expected device ID data.

[image: Cirrus WM8926 Datasheet rev 4.4 Figure 63]

Comment: Thank you! This was it. I wrote 0x00 first then 0x01 as the register addresses.